# Stars rhombus using c++

Tags: c++

How can I output the below asterisks in rhombus shape in c++ using the least number of loops and variables. Maximum no. of stars = n (input taken from the user)

```
  *
 * *
* * * = n
 * * 
  *
```

I tried doing it with just 2 loops but didn't succeed plus the program is too complicated to understand so didn't include it here.

So any algorithms you can think of?

Comment: homework??? if so pls tag accordingly :)

Comment: Is there a specific order that we need to follow? It's an interesting assignment.

Comment: @Sanjay no this is not homework :D
I just wanted to do this with the least possible loops and variables.

Comment: @CppLearner no specifics . . .I just want to display a rhombus for 'n' input with just 2 loops if possible and lowest no. of variables.

Comment: People this question is NOT a HOMEWORK so please stop fighting over it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common question for education I believe, and thus a Google search is very helpful.

Here is a ready made solution in Visual C++ (as some people learn better from code examples, the choice is yours)...

http://www.softwareandfinance.com/Visual_CPP/Loops_Diamond_Pattern.html

**EDIT**: Trying to reduce the for loops and keeping the spacing between stars, this is my best effort...

```
int i, j;
int n = 0;
std::cout << "Enter the maximum number of *:";
std::cin >> n;

std::cout << "\n\n";

for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
{
      std::cout.width(n - i);
      std::cout.fill(' ');
      std::cout << "";

      for (j = 1; j <= i; j++)
            std::cout << "* ";

      std::cout.width(n - i);
      std::cout.fill(' ');
      std::cout << "";

      std::cout << "\n";
}

for (i = n - 1; i >= 1; i--)
{
      std::cout.width(n - i);
      std::cout.fill(' ');
      std::cout << "";

      for (j = 1; j <= i; j++)
            std::cout << "* ";

      std::cout.width(n - i);
      std::cout.fill(' ');
      std::cout << "";

      std::cout << "\n";
}

std::cout << "\n";
```

**ONLY 2 LOOPS USED**:

```
int i, j;
int n = 0, c = 0, inc = 1;
std::cout << "Enter the maximum number of *:";
std::cin >> n;

std::cout <<"\n\n";

for (i = 1; i <= (n * 2) - 1; i++)
{
    c += inc;
    if(i == n)
        inc = -1;

    std::cout.width(n - c);
    std::cout.fill(' ');
    std::cout << "";

    for (j = 1; j <= c; j++)
        std::cout << "* ";

    std::cout.width(n - c);
    std::cout.fill(' ');
    std::cout << "";

    std::cout <<"\n";
}

std::cout <<"\n";
```

Comment: @thiton: Neither does having the mindset to cheat by asking for the answer, but I cannot decide people's morales and motivations for them. Besides, when does homework stop? We go out, and get paid jobs, and just have more 'assignments' to do... what makes this ok to look for ready made solutions (some people learn better through code examples). Also, I force nobody to click my links, the choice is there for the OP

Comment: *"This program is written in Turbo C programming language"* **Hmm...**

Comment: @musefan The link is great but that's not what I want. I want to restrict the program code to just 2 loops (if that's possible, which I think it is).

Comment: @shrishaster: I am not sure you can with 2 loops. The inner loops here are used to output the spacing (padding) as this is an unknown variable length

Comment: @musefan So can you please update your answer with the code that takes the least no. of loops and variable according to you so that I can work from there on . .

Comment: @shrishaster: Do you need the spaces in the diamond? (like your sample)? and should the next line be only 1 more (or less) star than the last?

Comment: @musefan +1 : If I ask a question, ready made answers/codes can help me, even if a homework :) Its all about your personal interest to understand further.

Comment: @shrishaster: I have added some code to show how it can be done. Also, I have manage to get code which has only 2 loops.

Comment: @Sanjay of course 'ready-made answers can help, even if homework'.  That's because there's no effort required on the learner's part.  You don't learn by submitting the correct answer, you learn by working towards finding it.  I wouldn't think a 'personal interest to understand further' would mean going out and merely acquiring the complete solution.  I thought we had decided not to post complete solutions to questions marked as homework? Good answer, but too good for the purpose of learning IMO.

Comment: @musefan You are good :) How much time did you take to do the 2 loops version? Also a small correction - there won't be the second 'int' in the second line of the code.

Comment: @shrishaster: Didn't take long really, just didn't have time to give my full concentration (just playing in between building other stuff)

Comment: @prelic. I dont recall saying I wouldn't post complete solutions to homework. Also, the OP didn't tag this as homework - it was wrongly done by a presumptive user. I personally learn a lot from ready made code, which I find the most useful answers are when I am on SO looking to learn how to do something new. I prefer the tidy consistent logic of code over the inconsistent incomplete ramblings of peoples perceptions on how to approach a problem. And based on the correction to my code that the OP has made, it seems clear they are reading and understanding what I have posted.

Answer (score 13):

That's not a pyramid, that's a rhombus :)

Anyway let's see the star number:

- n=1 -> 1 star
- n=2 -> 4 stars
- n=3 -> 9 stars

The pattern looks like twice the sum from 1 to n minus n (because the middle row exists once not twice), so `s(n) = 2 * (1+n)/2 * n - n = (1+n)*n-n` = `n*n` hey it's the area of a square!  Well how surprising. :-)

Now how to draw a n-sized rhombus:

- there will be `2*n-1` rows
- each row is `w = 2*n-1` characters wide
- each ith row (starting from i=0) has `m = min(i+1, 2*n-1-i)` stars, and `m-1` spaces between them
- so each row needs `w - (m) - (m-1)` spaces of space padding at sides, i.e. `w/2` on left and on right.

Now go write it! :)

Comment: +1 for giving useful guidance on homework rather than a ready made solution

Comment: I think you can look at that as pyramid, if you just treat the middle star as the vertex point. Now of course it's up to how we arrange the order....

Comment: Rhombus? I see a pyramid casting it's reflection over a nearby lake ;)

Comment: Ready-made algorithms don't help homework! (don't worry, I upvoted you for your apparently sound logic)

Comment: @musefan :) I believe it's mostly a programming practice, so in such situations I tend to present a reasoning and sometimes pseudocode (as an example on how to think when solving problems) and I leave out the actual technical/ programming part. Is it still too much on my side? (Knights of Cydonia is an awesome song btw)

Comment: Not at all too much, you have a great answer here!

Answer (score 1):

Two loops? Surely you can get by with just one.. Here is a rough description of the alogirthm I came up with:

- Loop through the (2*n-1)^2 square
- Determine the amount of stars needed on the current row (i.e. distance to the row with n stars)
- Determine the distance from the middle of the current index
- If the absolute distance of the current index is smaller than the amount of stars on that row, it needs a star in odd/even indices depending if n is odd/even.
- Add endlines end of rows

And here's a near [IOCC](http://www.ioccc.org/)-worthy quick improvisation of the algorithm that draws the rhombus with 2 variables, the loop counter and n=amount of stars in the middle row.

```
#include <cmath>
void print_rhombus(int n) 
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= ((2*n-1)*(2*n-1)); ++i) {        
        if ((abs((((2*n-1)+1)/2)-(i%(2*n-1) == 0?2*n-1:i%(2*n-1)))) - (n-abs((i%(2*n-1)==0?(i/(2*n-1)):(i/(2*n-1))+1) - n)) < 0 && (
                (n%2==1 && ((n-abs((i%(2*n-1)==0?(i/(2*n-1)):(i/(2*n-1))+1) - n))%2==1 && (i%(2*n-1) == 0?2*n-1:i%(2*n-1))%2 == 1 || (n-abs((i%(2*n-1)==0?(i/(2*n-1)):(i/(2*n-1))+1) - n))%2==0 && (i%(2*n-1) == 0?2*n-1:i%(2*n-1))%2==0)) || 
                (n%2==0 && ((n-abs((i%(2*n-1)==0?(i/(2*n-1)):(i/(2*n-1))+1) - n))%2==1 && (i%(2*n-1) == 0?2*n-1:i%(2*n-1))%2 == 0 || (n-abs((i%(2*n-1)==0?(i/(2*n-1)):(i/(2*n-1))+1) - n))%2==0 && (i%(2*n-1) == 0?2*n-1:i%(2*n-1))%2==1))
                )) {
            std::cout << "*"; 
        } else { 
            std::cout << " "; 
        } 
        if (i%(2*n-1) == 0 && (n-abs((i%(2*n-1)==0?(i/(2*n-1)):(i/(2*n-1))+1) - n)) == n) {
            std::cout << " = " << n << std::endl; 
        }
        else if (i%(2*n-1) == 0) { 
            std::cout << std::endl; 
        }
    }    
}
```

It also prints the " = N", which I suppose may not have been the requirement. As you can see, sometimes a couple of extra descriptive variables would go a long ways. And if this were homework, you'd better be prepared to explain it..

Comment: Brilliant! The code works. I guess the abs() function helps to eliminate the need for second loop.

Comment: The abs was a quick way to get the distance to the middle. You can do it too without using the cmath method if that's needed..

Answer (score 0):

Break the task down.

1) First write a program that outputs a square of asterisks. In the example above (n = 3, I think) a five by five square will contain all the asterisks you want to output. Two loops (one inside the other) is the way to do this.

2) Now you have all the asterisks you need, work out formulas for which asterisks should be skipped to get the diamond pattern you want. If you decide an asterisk should be skipped you output a space instead.

All programming is like this, you're faced with a complex problem, you break it down into smaller sub-problems.

Comment: I get your strategy to solve it but solving itself is not the problem. The challenge hear is that I have to solve the whole program with just 2 loops!

Answer (score 0):

Not filled rhombus like this one:

```
   *  
  * *  
 *   * 
*     *
 *   * 
  * *  
   *
```

Code c++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int w=7;
    int h=7;
    string fill("*");
    string empty(" ");
    for (int i = 0; i<w; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j<h; j++)
        {
            if((j == h/2-i) or (j == h/2+i) or (j == -h/2+i) or (j+i == h+h/2-1) ) cout << fill;
            else cout <<empty;
        }
        cout<<endl;
        
    }
}
```